# how to animate currently pressed button to flash using two images between 3 buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

I'm stuck on a problem,  the game is a word game and I've given 3 hints, among 3 buttons,

The user needs to know which button he last pressed:

How to animate the "currently pressed" button to flash from one image to the other?

Images: 1st image name "candle_01.png" 2nd image name "candle2_03.png"

code for three buttons:

```
- (IBAction)firstHintq:(id)sender 
{
    hintView.text = @"founded in 1996, and is a sub of telecome";

    if (!btn1Pressed) 
    {
        if ((coins -10) >= 0)
        {
            coins = coins -10;
            score = score -2;

            coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];

            [_candleone setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.candletwo.hidden = NO;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

            CGPoint center = [_candletwo center];
            center.x = 88;
            center.y = 70;
            [_candletwo setCenter:center];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            btn1Pressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
 }

- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender 
{
    hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";

    if (!btn2Pressed) 
    {
        if ((coins -10) >= 0)
        {
            coins = coins -10;
            score = score -2;

            coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];

            [_candletwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
            self.candlethree.hidden = NO;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

            CGPoint center = [_candlethree center];
            center.x = 160;
            center.y = 70;
            [_candlethree setCenter:center];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            btn2Pressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)thirdHintq:(id)sender 
{
    hintView.text = @"Type in the third hint here";

    if (!btn3Pressed) 
    {
        if ((coins -10) >= 0)
        {
            coins = coins -10;
            score = score -2;

            [_candlethree setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
            btn3Pressed = true; 
        }    
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem though?

Comment: When you set a new image to you currently pressed UIButton,it doesn't change the image???

Comment: No it changes the image.... But I'd like that current button to flash from one image to the next! letting the user know that he is on that hint!